# What flowering plant is this in the New Orleans, Louisiana area?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

What is this small daisy like (quarter size) flowering plant? It has little seeds that stick to you like burrs.

[image]
[image]

It’s in the backyard of a place we are visiting.  The honey bees love it.

In New Orleans, Louisiana, USA.

UPDATE:  Here is another image with only the leaves of the plant.   As you can see the leave are not feathery as those of the Cosmo, they are spear-shaped and sometimes seated at the edges.

[image]

Comment: The orange one is lantana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely *[Bidens pilosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidens_pilosa)*, otherwise known as beggar's ticks. Check out this page on [hitchhikers](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/plmay98.htm) and then do an image search on Bidens pilosa images. I think you will see the seeds, flowers and leaves. Bidens is known in colder regions as a great summer occupant of hanging baskets and in greenhouses attracts a lot of bees.

Comment: Beggar’s Tick (Bidens pilosa), also know as Blackjack is correct.  Thank you!  It seems to be an annual Aster family plant that can be rather invasive.  Cnt find the zone it is limited to, but I will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of seeds I am pretty sure it's a species of [Cosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_(plant)) but I don't know which are its leaves in your picture, so I can't tell the exact species. By the colour of petals I think it can be Cosmos bipinnatus, Cosmos caudatus or Cosmos parviflorus.

Comment: C. parviflorus Flower is almost right, and is not correct because the leaves are not feather for the plant I am looking for.  The leaves are a little serated and are a spearhead shape, see image.  The s Ed’s are individual burrs too.  They stick to everything.